# Google Maps V2 override blue dot behavior

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm running a Map V2 based app and I need to override the blue dot behavior so it will stay fixed and not move or draw the accuracy radius.

I use `map.setMyLocationEnabled(true)`because it gives me the **MyLocationButton** on the top right corner, and basically it also creates the blue dot.

Your help is appreciated

Example photo (not mine) of the blue dot, the accuracy radius it draws and the MyLocationButton
[image]

Comment: Remove `setMyLocationEnabled(true)` and float your own button over the map.

Comment: Thank you CommonsWare. Any idea about how to do that ?

Comment: The same way that you float any widget over any other widget: use a layout that supports it, like `RelativeLayout` or `FrameLayout`. [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Containers/RelativeOverlap) shows two `Button` widgets in a `RelativeLayout`, with one floating over the other. I suspect that you would have to use `MapView` directly, though there may be recipes for tweaking the UI of a `MapFragment`/`SupportMapFragment` this way.

Comment: I actually use SupportMapFragment. Thanks again.